# How to Send PHP form POST values to a CGI url?

Tags: php, forms, post, request, cgi

i want to send php values to a cgi url

```
 <form method="post" action="https://192.168.10.1:10443/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi" style="float:left">
                    <input name="ACTION" value="disable" type="hidden">
                    <input name="line" value="0" type="hidden">
                </form>
```

these values i want to send with PHP POST request to url

> https://192.168.10.1:10443/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi

can any one help me how to do this.

Comment: You have `cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi` twice in the action attribute. You can also check [this tutorial](http://www.rebol.com/docs/cgi2.html) for more information.

Comment: Look up cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a submit button

```
  <form action="https://192.168.10.1:10443/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi" method="POST">
       <input type="submit" value="Publish">
       <input name="ACTION" value="disable" type="hidden">
       <input name="line" value="0" type="hidden">
 </form>
```

for further reference: http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/Cgi/textareas.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "submit" button, it's all it takes.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="https://192.168.10.1:10443/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi" style="float:left">
    <input name="ACTION" value="disable" type="hidden">
    <input name="line" value="0" type="hidden">

    <!-- submit button -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but value is not passing nothing happing

Comment: I edited my answer to show the full code. This works, I tried in my server and it works. Of course you are just posting an empy "line" variable. And I have no access to your "https://192.168.10.1:10443/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi" so it just returns an error, but the form is posted

Comment: btw, you should not use javascript to post a form unless you need to. It's bad coding to use javascript when you dont need it, it only makes it more complicated, slower, and adds nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send automatically. Without pressing the button. Otherwise, why do you need hidden fields?

```
  <form method="post" action="https://192.168.10.1:10443/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi" style="float:left">
        <input name="ACTION" value="disable" type="hidden">
        <input name="line" value="0" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
    </script>
```

Comment: but value is not passing nothing happing

Comment: Try to insert my code and open "Network" in the browser and you'll see that the request was sent

Comment: If you want to get an answer on the page then you need to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: i tryed your code but page redirect to https://192.168.10.1:10443/cgi-bin/outgoingfw.cgi page but value not passing no action is happing on that page

Answer (score -1):

[You need to submit the sending of the form, this can be done on javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)